# Automorphism group of a non_abelian p_group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

Let G be a non abelian p_group. When is set of all automorphisms group of G a p_group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the power of $p$ there is a classification. For example, amongst all $p$-groups of order $p^5$, with $p>2$ prime, there is exactly *one* group whose automorphism group is again a $p$-group -- see [here](http://journals.cambridge.org/article_S000497270002757X). It has order $p^6$.
However, although it seems to be difficult to find finite $p$-groups for $p>2$ whose automorphism group is a $p$-group, there is an asymptotic result: [The automorphism group of a finite p-group is almost always a p-group](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869307000142).